# difference between new[ ] / delete [ ] vs new / delete in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I have a very quick question: What is the difference between `new[ ]` / `delete [ ]` vs `new` / `delete` in C++ when it comes to Dynamic memory?

Is  `new[ ]` / `delete [ ]` not belong to Dynamic memory?

Comment: You use `new` to allocate one object, and `new[]` to allocate an array of objects. You use the form of delete that matches the new you used. Only please don't actually use any of the above. For a single object, use `make_unique` or `make_shared`, and for an array use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

`new` allocates memory for a single item and calls its constructor, and `delete` calls its destructor and frees its memory.

`new[]` allocates memory for an array of items and calls their constructors, and `delete[]` calls their destructors and frees the array memory.

Answer (score 1):

Both memory allocation mechanisms work with dynamic memory. The former creates/destroys a single object, the second creates/destroys a run-time sized array of objects. That's the difference.

Other than that, these two mechanisms are two completely separate independent dynamic memory management mechanisms. E.g. allocating an array consisting of 1 element using `new[]` is not equivalent to simply using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

the difference detween the two is that those with [] are those for array.

The difference is not that visible for the `new` keyword as there is no error possible

```
int *i = new int;
Object *array = new Object[100];
```

however you should make shure to call the good one to make shure destructor are called has the should

```
delete i; // ok
delete[] array; //ok
delete array; // Careffull, all destructors may not be called
```